How to allow users in realm to manage only particular set of other users in Keycloak?
I have a custom realm, where I have 3 realm roles specified. These 3 roles will have to be probably grouped together with some particular name of group. How to allow users of one role to manage other users in the group?
I tried switching up Client Authentication for security-admin-console, then setting up policies with permissions for a Client role in security-admin-console Client, then assigning this role to one of the 3 realm roles, but when I login through this security-admin-console, it returns 401 cause it lacks client credentials. I couldn't find info how to make security-admin-console automatically authenticate to Keycloak with client credentials. Can someone advice what would be the right direction here?
